# Hide header section after last record

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report, whenever I reach the last record, it will print another extra page together with the header.

See the attachment below:

[image: this is extra page, always appear together with the header section after last record]

I applied formula to the Detail Section and Header Section at the suppress.

Detail Section:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global BooleanVar finished;
finished :=  OnLastRecord
```

Header Section:

```
Global BooleanVar finished
```

It seems working for the layout, but when the extra page is not printed:

1. my last record is not appear (let's say I have 51 records, only 50 records is printed)

[image: First Problem after applying formula]

2. If I have only one record, the next page still appear

Is there any correction which can be applied on my formula, or am I applying a wrong formula to it?

Comment: why are you applying on detail section? I don't think you need the supress condition in detail section

Comment: The formula in detail section is not for suppress. It just to check whether the report reach Last Record or Not. My logic is, while printing, it will check whether the report reach LastRecord or not, if it reach LastRecord, the boolean operation will return true and the header will be suppress. Do you have any other option Siva? Thank you