# Missing last record in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am using below code for suppressing pageheader

```
 Whileprintingrecords;
    Global BooleanVar finished;
    finished := OnLastRecord
```

In crystal report last record is missing every time because of that code, please give me any solution for this guys

Comment: Maybe the formula is used on detail-section too?

Comment: i used in detail section only , in detail section i am checking whether the current record is last record or not then i am using "global booleanvar" in page header suppress section

Comment: So your goal is to suppress page header on last page?

Comment: yes, now suppress is working but its hiding last record , i checked records count  its showing correct count

Answer (score 0):

The formula in your question returns a boolean and therefore suppresses the last record. 
But to achieve what you want, there's no need for a global variable at all.

To suppress the page header on the last page you can use following formula:

```
PageNumber = TotalPageCount
```

Depending on the data, the report may only have one page. So if you want to keep the header if the report has only one page then you can use following formula:

```
TotalPageCount > 1 And PageNumber = TotalPageCount
```

Comment: my issues is, If any record will go to second page then only page header should show in second page, else it should not show.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean...You want to show the page header only on second page? Or do you want to suppress everything but the page header on second page?

Comment: if one page is full and second page not having any records in PDF  that time it is showing page header, That Means page header is  showing with empty records, if there is empty records it should be suppress so i written that code , that code not only suppressing page header it is suppressing last record of the page also

Comment: Three things come to my mind: **1.** `New Page After` is activated on a section. **2.** A section requires too much space in height and causes a page break. **3.** The option `Suppress Blank Section` on the detail-section is not activated.

Answer (score 0):

You have similar issue like me before. [Hide Header Section After Last Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863804/hide-header-section-after-last-record)

Unfortunately, I still cannot resolve this issue with the correct solution.

What I did last time, I set number of record for each page by using remainder formula